# Proper installation when replacing particle board underlayment with 3/4 advantec over 1/2" plywood subfloor?

Tags: subfloor, underlayment

My home's flooring was originally 1/2 plywood subfloor with 3/4 particle board underlayment. I have since removed the particle board and plan to replace it with 3/4 Advantec. My current plan is:

1. Secure the 1/2 plywood to the joists via 1-1/8 decking screws.
2. Cover subfloor with 15 lbs roofing paper to prevent squeaking.
3. Install 3/4 Advantec underlayment perpendicular to the subfloor and secure 
   with 1-1/2 staples (Not stapling into joists).

Are there any issues with the steps I've listed above?  I asked a gentleman at Lowes and he said, "The roofing paper is not necessary and be sure to *nail* the Advantec to the joists. Another person said, "Glue and nail the Advantec to the subfloor but do not nail into the joists." I cannot seem to find information that clearly explains best process given my situation.